# Swiftでの「Dictionary型」戻り値について

Tags: swift, xcode

```
func getJson(param: models)-> Dictionary{
    let url = "https://test.com/" + models + ".php"
    let json = JSON(data:super.HttpRequest())
    print(json.type) /* print結果 "Dictionary" */
    print(json) /* jsonの内容は意図したデータが帰ってきております。 */
    print(json['name']) /* 左の指定で「山田太郎」も問題ございません。 */
    return json
}
/* call */
myClass.getJson()
```

httpRequestを実行し、jsonデータを受信するためのプログラムを作成しておりますが、
戻り値のデータ型を「Dictionary」にすると、
「Reference to generic type 'Dictionary' requires arguments in <...>」というエラーになってしまいます。
JSON関数から受け取った状態の「json」変数のtypeを「print」しても「Dictionary」となるのですが、戻り値の「->Dictionary」のところがエラーになります。

ご教授いただけませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージの内容は、「`Dictionary`を関数の返り値とする場合にはジェネリクス型の指定（たとえば、`Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`）をする必要がある」というものですが、ここでは関係ありません。

SwiftyJSONを利用されているのだと思われますが、`type`プロパティが返却する型情報は単にJSONのルート要素の型を示しており、Swift上での型は`JSON`になります。

```
func getJson(param: models) -> JSON {
    let url = "https://test.com/" + models + ".php"
    let json = JSON(data:super.HttpRequest())
    return json
}
```

Comment: quesera2様

的確なご指摘ありがとうございました。
ご指摘部分の修正で問題なく動作いたしました。
誠にありがとうございました。